# Headless Passthrough: QEMU-KVM NVidia

Tags: nvidia, kvm-virtualization, qemu, headless

Is it possible to run VM and instead of sending picture to monitor, encode VM screen as x264 video stream and send stream over network?

**PS** I have OpenGL app that runs on Linux and I wish to stream video that app is generating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OBS Studio
https://obsproject.com/

Here is youtube video that does what you have asked
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3HL9x0CEtY